# Materialize tabs z-index indicator not working on safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, materialize

I'm using materialize.css for my front end, and i styled the tab indicator. It seems like there's a problem with the tab's link. It's working fine on other browser, but there's something wrong on Safari. Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Top: Safari, Bottom: other browser

And here's my stylesheet.

```css
#siteplan-content .section #siteplan-tabs {
    padding-top: 55px;
}

#siteplan-content .section #siteplan-tabs ul li {
    display: block;
    z-index: 99;
    color: #fff;
    /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

#siteplan-content .section #siteplan-tabs ul.tabs {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: 'Fontin', regular;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    left: -11.4px;
    z-index: 62;
}

#siteplan-content .section #siteplan-tabs ul li a,
#siteplan-content .section #siteplan-tabs ul li a.active {
    color: #fff !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    z-index: 62 !important;
}

#siteplan-content .section #siteplan-tabs ul li a.active {
    color: #fff !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
    /*z-index: 10002 !important;*/
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

#siteplan-content .section #siteplan-tabs ul.tabs .indicator {
    background-color: #7e735b;
    height: 48px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 61;
}
```

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="col s12 m12 center" id="siteplan-tabs" style="color: #fff !important;">
    <ul class="tabs hide-on-small-only">
        <li class="tab col s2"><a class="active" href="#test1" onclick="siteplan()"><?php echo getSiteplanTitle('2') ?></a></li>
        <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#regent-content" onclick="regent()"><?php echo getSiteplanTitle('3') ?></a></li>
        <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#signature-content" onclick="signature()"><?php echo getSiteplanTitle('4') ?></a></li>
        <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#titan-content" onclick="titan()"><?php echo getSiteplanTitle('5') ?></a></li>
   <!-- <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#ultimate-content" onclick="ultimate()">Ultimate</a></li> -->
        <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#venture-content" onclick="venture()"><?php echo getSiteplanTitle('7') ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

FYI: I'm using Safari 5.1.7 for Windows.

Comment: Please include your markup as well so we can reproduce the issue completely

Comment: @TylerH Hi Tyler, please check my question again.

Comment: Sorry, I should specify that we need the outputted markup, not the PHP code. Also note that Safari 5.1.7 is a Windows version, and Safari for Windows has not been supported for a long time.